# How to install PyWPS on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wps, pywps

Since PyWPS is not yet packaged for Ubuntu an installation guide would be handy. This guide should target a vanilla Ubuntu LTS install, detailing the required dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide was successfully tested with PyWPS 3.2 on Ubuntu 10.04, 12.04 and 14.04. Throughout the guide `pico` is used to edit files, but you can use your text editor of choice instead.

**1. Installation**

Install dependencies, clone the project from GitHub and install it:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 python-setuptools python-magic python-lxml  git-core wget

git clone https://github.com/geopython/PyWPS.git

cd ./PyWPS

sudo python setup.py install
```

**2. Create folders for PyWPS assets**

For convenience, in this example all PyWPS assets are stored in `/var/www`, a typical setup for a development environment. In a server setup it might be wiser to store processes in `/srv` and logs in `/var/log`.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/pywps

sudo mkdir /var/www/wpsoutputs

sudo cp -R pywps/processes /var/www/pywps
```

Create log and configuration files:

```
sudo touch /var/www/pywps/pywps.log

sudo cp pywps/default.cfg /var/www/pywps/pywps.cfg

sudo pico /var/www/pywps/pywps.cfg
```

In the configuration file only the *Server* environment needs to be tweaked, in order to match the asset locations created before. The set up of the GRASS and MapServer environments are left for a later date.

> ```
>     [server] 
>     maxoperations=30
>     maxinputparamlength=1024 
>     maxfilesize=500mb
>     tempPath=/tmp
>     processesPath=/var/www/pywps/processes
>     outputUrl=http://localhost/wpsoutputs
>     outputPath=/var/www/wpsoutputs 
>     debug=true # deprecated since 3.2, use logLevel instead
>     logFile=/var/www/pywps/pywps.log
> ```

Pass ownership to the *www-data* user (again, in a server setup you might want to be more conservative):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/pywps /var/www/wpsoutputs
```

**3. Configure the web service**

Copy the PyWPS CGI to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`:

```
sudo cp webservices/cgi/pywps.cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin

whereis wps.py
```

Copy the path of `wps.py` to the clipboard.

```
sudo pico /usr/lib/cgi-bin/pywps.cgi
```

Modify `pywps.cgi` to match the present setup:

> ```
>     export PYWPS_CFG=/var/www/pywps/pywps.cfg 
>     export PYWPS_PROCESSES=/var/www/pywps/processes/
>
>     /usr/local/bin/wps.py $1
> ```

Give it a try:

```
cd /usr/lib/cgi-bin

sudo sh pywps.cgi "request=GetCapabilities&service=WPS"
```

Make sure Apache is configured to run CGI scripts; the CGI module might need to be explicitly enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod cgid
```

Edit the default site configuration (Ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04):

```
sudo pico /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

In Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo pico /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Verify that this section is included, add the necessary keywords to make it look like this (in Ubuntu 12.04 this may already be the default configuration):

> ```
>     ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
>     <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
>             AllowOverride None
>             Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
>             Order allow,deny
>             Allow from all
>     </Directory>
> ```

Restart Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**4. Testing**

From the command line:

```
wget -O response.xml -v "http://localhost/cgi-bin/pywps.cgi?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WPS"

wget -O response.xml -v "http://localhost/cgi-bin/pywps.cgi?REQUEST=Execute&IDENTIFIER=dummyprocess&SERVICE=WPS&VERSION=1.0.0&DATAINPUTS=Input1=1;Input2=1"
```

The same URLs can be used in a browser like Firefox.

Comment: for 4. Testing, it's small letter `i` for `input1` and `input2`

Comment: using apache2 on ubuntu 14.04 you might want to put the files in `var/www/html`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there are currently efforts to add PyWPS to [UbuntuGIS](https://github.com/geopython/pywps/issues/114).